# Deep linking to UINavigationController item/view

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar with 5 tabs. One of those tabs is:

```
UITabBarItem *profile = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Profile" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab.png"] tag:5];
```

Withing that tab bar view (profiles view controller), I want a UIButton to link to friends within a UINavigationController. So the friends view controller will have a back button to the profile.

Is there a way from another view controller (say my first tab) to link to the friends controller and have the back button still go to profiles?